# JS plugin script loading but not working

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I am trying to create a theme using [curtains.js](https://github.com/Victa/curtain.js/blob/development/v2.0/curtain.js) but am having a few problems. I have both registered and enqueued the script and the part that would go in the footer like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tf_load_custom_scripts');

function tf_load_custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('curtain', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/curtain.js', array('jquery'), 2.0 ); 
    wp_register_script('curtain-instance', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/curtain-instance.js', array('curtain','jquery'), true ); 

    if( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('curtain');
        wp_enqueue_script('curtain-instance');
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true );

}
```

I've also changed all the `$` to `jQuery` to comply with no-conflict rules.

My scripts all seem to be loading fine but not running. I'm probably missing something very obvious. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: No errors (aside for a couple of css ones that have nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Posted code is good. (Only a tip: `wp_enqueue_script('curtain');` is not needed once you registered 'curtain' as a dependence for 'curtain-instance' that is enqueued the next line) But sure problem is not this. Again, this code is good (and if all the files you enqueue are where you search for them) what causes the problem 99,99% is somewhere else. If your js code is wp-related post here, if not try asking stackoverflow.

Comment: I think you might be onto something. I'm compiling it using codekit and the minified file is in the wrong place but I thought that it didn't matter since I'm using the originals. I'll have to look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Is your script compatible with the version of jQuery bundled with WordPress?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. 1.10.2 Probably not. Actually it looks like its version 1.7.1. Its not maintained anymore. I guess that means I need to look for a different plugin? Good call. If you want to put this as an answer I'll check it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress-specific script issues are generally limited to one of the following:

1. Improperly enqueued script

   Proper script enqueueing involves use of `wp_enqueue_script()`. If the script is properly enqueued, you will see a `<script....>` link in the document head or footer
2. Not accounting for jQuery no-conflict mode

   WordPress-bundled jQuery is configured for no-conflict mode, which requires wrapping scripts in `jquery(document).ready(function({})`
3. The script not being compatible with the version of jQuery bundled with WordPress

   As of WordPress 3.6, the bundled version of jQuery is 1.10.2, which is known to cause some compatibility with some outdated scripts

Comment: Correct for number 3 in my case. I tested it in html and fixed it there with jquery-migrate. Still having problems with the wordpress site though. Although I put `true`as the last parameter my scripts are still appearing in the header. I think this might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the jQuery/Java script with JSfiddle? It seems like these scripts do not execute when you call them improperly. Like wrapping the script in the head, body, domready etc...

Try this  `jQuery(document).ready(function () { Your code here});`

Comment: As a note, if he loads the files in the footer, he might not need to add `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I've tried both that and without the `(document).ready`. Everything works fine in html.